# where i can download oracle system views like sql server system views map?

Tags: oracle

where i can download oracle system views like sql server system views map ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select *
from dictionary;
```

This will give you a list of the objects in Oracle's data dictionary and most rows also have a decent description of what it contains.

If you really need the visual, TUSC offers a poster for at least the V$ views on 10g:
http://www.tusc.com/oracle/download/tusc_posters.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this; "Oracle Database 11g: Interactive Quick Reference": http://www.oracle.com/go/?&Src=7027600&Act=54&pcode=WWOU10044054MPP047